# I am a beginning java coder looking for help on how to import my .class or .java source file into an executable jar file

Tags: java, import, executable

I was looking to surprise my parents with this nifty little program I made in jCreator at school, any and all help is appreciated.
My problem is that any advanced instructions wouldn't be understood by myself, so I ask that you word your answer in a way a beginner would understand. I have access to the JDK at school so that shouldn't be a problem, please list any necessary materials I may need as well. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calender {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("\nCALENDER.JAVA\n");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Determine birthstone using numbers 1-12 represent     calender months");
        System.out.print("Enter Month Number ===>> ");
        int month = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        switch (month){
            case 1: System.out.println("January Garnet");   break;
            case 2: System.out.println("February    Amethyst"); break;
            case 3: System.out.println("March   Aquamarine");   break;
            case 4: System.out.println("April   Diamond");  break;
            case 5: System.out.println("May Emerald");  break;
            case 6: System.out.println("June    Pearl / Alexandrite");  break;
            case 7: System.out.println("July    Ruby"); break;
            case 8: System.out.println("August  Peridot");  break;
            case 9: System.out.println("September   Sapphire"); break;
            case 10: System.out.println("October    Opal / Tourmaline");    break;
            case 11: System.out.println("November   Citrine / Topaz");  break;
            case 12: System.out.println("December   Tanzanite / Turquoise / Zircon");   break;
            default : System.out.println("This is not a valid entry.");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly your question is ?

Comment: Which class you need to import and where it's located? You could use import statement as you did for import java.util.Scanner class with your package name if any.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)'s the official Oracle tutorial on creating a JAR through the command line.

[Here](http://www.jcreator.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=52)'s a JCreator specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

Follow following steps as below:-

1.) Place your file in a package structure and also declare it on top of java code.

2.) Set PATH environment variable to point where JDK is installed.

2.a ) also create a manifest file in same folder in which you define the main class 
3.) open cmd navigate to the package location and run following command:-

```
jar cf 'jar-file-name'.jar 'input-file(s)'
```

4.) Run the following jar file by command

```
java -jar <jar file name >
```

Answer (score 0):

from commmand line:

jar cvfm nameOfJar.jar yourClass.class

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to make an executable jar that contains this class.  You can create such a jar with

```
jar cvfe calender.jar Calender *.class
```

Once it's created, you can then run it using `java -jar calender.jar`.